# New user registration submits null IDs to Postgres database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, omniauth, form-for, strong-parameters

I'm having an issue with new user registrations, and  I've spent the last week searching for an answer. I noticed the issue when I was attempting to add Omniauth to my Rails app, starting off with just Github. After a user signs in with Github, they go to the regular devise signup page to answer a couple more questions before signing in. I am able to successfully create a new user, however when I look at the db, it shows both university_id and program_id as null. When I looked at the server logs, I noticed a `Unpermitted parameters: code, university_id, program_id` error. I don't believe Omniauth has anything to do with this error per se since it's happening whether or not they choose to sign in with Github first. My suspicion is that it has something to do with the strong params. Any suggestions out there?

Registrations Controller:

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  # GET /resource/sign_up
  def new
    @universities = University.all
    @programs = Program.all
    super
  end

  # POST /resource
  def create

    if params["user"]["code"] == ENV["CODE_TO_SIGN_UP"]
      User.create(user_params)
    else
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { return redirect_to new_user_registration_path, notice: 'The code you entered was wrong. Please contact ' + ENV["ADMIN_EMAIL"] }
      end
    end

    super
  end
end

protected

    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :github, :time_zone, :university, :program, :password)
    end
end
```

User Model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :university
   belongs_to :program
end
```

University Model:

```
class University < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :programs
    has_many :users, through: :programs
end
```

Program Model:

```
class Program < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :university
    has_many :users, through: :university
end
```

new.html.erb:

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
(...other fields)
 <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :university_id, 'University' %><br />
    <%= f.collection_select(:university_id, University.all, 'id', 'name') %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :program_id, 'Program' %><br>
    <%= f.collection_select(:program_id, Program.all, 'id', 'name') %>
  </div>
  (...other fields)
<% end %>
```

**Github Login**
User Model:

```
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
                 :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :omniauthable, :omniauth_providers => [:github]

def self.from_omniauth(auth)
        where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_create do |user|
            user.email = auth.info.email
            user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
            user.full_name = auth.info.name   # assuming the user model has a name
            # If you are using confirmable and the provider(s) you use validate emails, 
            # uncomment the line below to skip the confirmation emails.
            # user.skip_confirmation!
        end
    end

    def self.new_with_session(params, session)
        super.tap do |user|
            if data = session["devise.github_data"] && session["devise.github_data"]["extra"]["raw_info"]
                user.email = data["email"] if user.email.blank?
            end
        end
    end
```

Application Controller

```
protected

def configure_permitted_parameters
   devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:github, :github_confirmation, :university_id, :program_id, :full_name, :time_zone])
end
```

Devise Initializer:

```
Devise.setup do |config|

  config.omniauth :github, "xxx", "xxx",
                  callback_url: "localhost:3000/users/auth/github/callback"
end
```

Gemfile:

```
gem 'devise', '~> 4.2'
gem 'omniauth'
gem 'omniauth-github'
```

If there's a bit of code I forgot to throw up, please let me know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `user_params` method, you're allowing `university` and `program` but in the form you're passing `university_id` and `program_id`. Allow these in addition to `code` in your `user_params` and it should work.

Rails will only permit the whitelisted parameters and disregard any others to prevent mass assignment. That's why `university_id` and other unpermitted params are nil in the database.

Comment: I should've mentioned, but I've tried several variations of params there, including `:university_id` and `:university_ids`. None seem to work. When I tried just `:university_id` and `:program_id` I received the error `Unpermitted parameters: code, full_name, github_confirmation, password_confirmation`. I actually have no idea what `code` refers to?

Comment: you're using `code` in your `create` action and could you please show how you set up signing up with GitHub?

Comment: Ah of course, sorry about that. I’m actually taking this project over so am not 100% familiar with what was there before I came on board. I’ve edited my post to reflect the Github login. I did notice that there is another set of permitted params within the application controller... could it be that they're conflicting somehow?

Comment: Wow I just added `program_id` and `university_id` to the configure_permitted_params in the application controller and that seems to have done the trick! Thanks for forcing me to look at **all** of the code I inherited!